# What is the best way to maintain element size consistency across 3.5 and 4 inch screens in iOS?

Tags: ios, ios7

How should I specify my element sizes so that they appear the same (or scaled appropriately) across screen sizes ? 
Also how to make sure images do not appear out of their aspect ratio when seen in different screen sizes ?

Answer (score 2):

Use "Auto Layout" feature presented in iOS6 or use "Spring and Struts" in nib files to maintain sizes or scale them appropriately and maintain their positions or reposition according to your requirements.

Use this line to maintain aspect ratio of your images:

```
[imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
```

Or you can also define in nib files and set UIImageView 'Mode' property in 'View' column in 'Attributes Inspector' tab as "Aspect Fit".

[click here to view Tutorial of Auto Layout & Spring and Struts](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1)

Answer (score 1):

**AutoLayout:**

Auto Layout in Xcode 5 provides powerful workflows for rapidly and easily creating and maintaining constraint-based layouts in OS X and iOS apps. With Xcode 5, you can:

1.Add constraints when you are ready

2.Quickly add constraints using control-drag or menu options

3.Update constraints and frames separately

4.Specify placeholder constraints for dynamic views

5.See, understand, and resolve issues with conflicting constraints or ambiguous views

[more](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)

[image]

[image]

**Without AutoLayout**

[image]

Handle 3.5 and 4 inch Screen

[image]

Use AutoSizing

[image]